# MD5 javascript implementation

Tags: php, javascript, forms, input, md5

i've a form in which user can inser a password in a `input text field`. I want to convert that string in md5 so in post to the action page i will have the md5 version of string and not the string. is possible to change value of input only in post side and not in input text ?

Something like this:

```
function go(){
   var pass = document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value;
   pass = md5(pass);
   form.pass.value=pass; 
}
```

is just a pseudocode. but in this way it will change the text insert by user in the md5 version. i want that user don't have to see it but in php page in action of form $_POST['pass'] will have md5 version of pass. i hope you understood. my english is not very good ;)

SOLUTION : 
HTTPS is best solution, but to avoid it is possible to create an input field hidden, fill it with md5 pass and clean the password field ;)

```
var rp = md5(pass.value);
document.rP.value=rp;
pass.value="";
```

Comment: Why you should have the password outputted anywhere (even if md5)? If you really need it somewhere, you should store it in a session.

Comment: You mean: 1. Enter password to the form in plain text like "ABC", but 2. send it not as plain text to the server? (So, md5() it before posting back? Then you need javascript or even better use HTTPS)

Comment: Your question needs to be a little clearer. Maybe you can give a basic overview of your code to aid explanation.

Comment: see edit :) i explain better ( i think :P )

Comment: @djot right! i want to send to server md5 pass.. i can use javascript but users will see the change of pass in the value of input text or not?

Comment: I think I understand it a little better, So you are saying you want to md5 it before the post action happens but you don't want the user to the see the md5 version. If so, then maybe use a hidden a text field to store the md5 version. I can't help much because I don't understand your overall problem. :)

Comment: This sounds like it will wreak havoc with password saver software. Just use HTTPS at least for the login.

Comment: ok.. the hidden text field is a solution, but i don't want to pass in post the plain text of pass.. in which way i select what i want to pass to server? if pass go anyway in plain text to server the hidden text field with md5 have no reason to exist

Comment: @Inerdial i can't use https cause i don't have dedicated server but only an hosting.. :(

Comment: I don't see any benefits to this.  MD5ing the password before sending it to the server won't stop a replay attack as all you have to do is send the same MD5 hash again. Not knowing what data the hash is a hash of isn't a problem.  If you need to send the data securely then you need to send it over HTTPS

Comment: if someone sniff someone the field pass in form is not in textplain but md5. and md5 is impossible to "decrypt"

Comment: md5 is not decryptable because it's not an encryption standard (it's a hash), but if the password is simple enough it can be EASILY recovered using md5 rainbow tables. Use HTTPS.

Comment: @JackTurky: With JS you can "extract" the password from the input field (which is dotted anyway if set to type="password"). You then decide if you send <input name="password" .../> or add a hidden field like e.g. <input type="hidden" name="password_md5"... /> ... Anyway, I bet you better use sessions, no passwords, and a hash which you store in the session and in your form (hidden) to do whatever you want to do.

Comment: @JackTurky As I said, it doesn't matter, if the form is not being submitted over HTTPS then it's vulnerable to a replay attack. You don't have to know what the hash was originally to send the same hash again.  also (this just occurred to me), you'll make your site completely inaccessible to anyone with javascript disabled.

Comment: @deed02392 Not if you hash a combination of username+password+constant gibberish. (Still vulnerable to gods know what, but not password recovery.)

Comment: anyway: http://phpjs.org/functions/md5:469

Comment: @JackTurky I think you only need a static IP, not a dedicated host for SSL to work. (That and a hosting provider that does, in fact, provide IP-based vhosts and setting them up with SSL certificates.)

Comment: @JackTurky: Maybe to narrow down the window of opportunity on replay attacks, you could send the server timestamp to the client, and ask him to send back the same timestamp and a hash of timestamp+password+whatever else. Then, on the server, only allow logins within a few minutes of the timestamp being issued. An attacker could still replay the hash for a few minutes, but not once it's too late.

Comment: Ignoring the problems with this which people have already identified, if you still want a Javascript MD5 function, try <a href="http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/index.html">this</a>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to go about this the wrong way.

The best solution is to use HTTPS. This means you don't have to worry about obfuscating the entered password.

In my solution I accept passwords in plain text over HTTPS and then go one step further by checking their password isn't one of 12,000 or so 'simple' passwords I have stored locally.

Comment: i know https.. i've studied it.. but i can't use it cause i'm not using a dedicated server..

Comment: You don't need a dedicated server to use it. Virtual hosting is sufficient although you may need cooperation with the hosting company.